# I do not know if this is hardware or software

Tags: firefox

Since my mom, age 82, purchased a Dell lap top several years ago.  A friend , computer edcation, helped her set it up.

Shortly or from the start, she gets an error script box that pops up right after she boots it up.  Everyone kept telling her to just close that box and proceed with her browser firefox.  Now 5 or so years later, I notices how slow it is running.

Here is the data in the box:
Line 30 char 3 library not registered code 0 url file://C:program % 20 files %20 (x86) Dell% 20 Script % 20 center/sscommon/common/inc/as/ss_shell included js

It then ask's, " do you want to continue scripts on this page

Yes or no...she has just hit the x button top or sometimes yes and sometimes no...I finally helped.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what the question is?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a bug in a program (probably broken code) at C:/Program Files (x86)/Dell Script center/sscommon/common/inc/as/ss_shell

As in it is some javascript based dell program that is causing it. It is harmless and doesn't matter if you press yes or no (if it's from Dell)

1. Download and install Malwarebytes and run a quick scan on the computer to clear out any viruses in it. (There are bound to be some)
2. Download ccleaner to run it's default cleaner (which clears out unneeded data like history and temporary files) and to fix registry errors.
3. Defragment the hard drive with a defragmenter of your choice (there is one built in to windows but I hear that one is not so good, try Auslogics' Defraggler instead)
4. Run (Windows Key + R) msconfig, go to the startup tab and clear out anything you don't know what is. (Take a close look at "Manufacturer" if you're unsure what something is, and then decide if you trust the manufacturer or not)

---

The above is just standard maintenance for a Windows machine, there are many alternatives to all the programs I mentioned. Doing this should fix the speed issues with the computer. And if you want to get rid of the error you get whenever you start the computer then look in msconfig's startup menu for anything from Dell and disable it all (you don't need it anyways unless it's something like a wireless network manager, in which case you possibly may need it) msconfig is a program that you can use to configure the startup process for your Windows based computer. But the thing that will really help the most with speed is step 3 (defragmenting) and it should be done regularily on a Windows PC (But it is not needed on Linux, Mac, Android or BSD. It is also not needed if you have an SSD or a  Flash based drive like phones normally do)